# How can I retrieve the identities of rows that were inserted through insert...select?

Tags: sql, sql-server, identity

I am inserting records through a query similar to this one:

```
insert into tbl_xyz select field1 from tbl_abc
```

Now I would like to retreive the newly generated IDENTITY Values of the inserted records. How do I do this with minimum amount of locking and maximum reliability?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can get this information using the [OUTPUT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) clause.

You can output your information to a temp target table or view.

Here's an example:

```
DECLARE @InsertedIDs TABLE (ID bigint)
INSERT into DestTable (col1, col2, col3, col4)
OUTPUT INSERTED.ID INTO @InsertedIDs
SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4 FROM SourceTable
```

You can then query the table InsertedIDs for your inserted IDs.

Comment: What?  That's freaking sweet!  When did that feature get added?

Answer (score 2):

@@IDENTITY will return you the last inserted IDENTITY value, so you have two possible problems

1. Beware of triggers executed when inserting into table_xyz as this may change the value of @@IDENTITY.
2. Does tbl_abc have more than one row. If so then @@IDENTITY will only return the identity value of the last row

Issue 1 can be resolved by using SCOPE__IDENTITY() instead of @@IDENTITY
Issue 2 is harder to resolve. Does field1 in tbl_abc define a unique record within tbl_xyz, if so you could reselect the data from table_xyz with the identity column. There are other solutions using CURSORS but these will be slow.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT @@IDENTITY
```

This is how I've done it before.  Not sure if this will meet the latter half of your post though.

**EDIT**
Found this link too, but not sure if it is the same...
[How to insert multiple records and get the identity value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/95988/how-to-insert-multiple-records-and-get-the-identity-value)

Comment: This will only retreive the identity of the last record inserted. I need to retreive all of them

Comment: I'm making this a favorite question.  I want to know the answer to that too :)

Comment: Do not ever use @@identity, it will not always return the correct value!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you can't really do this with straight SQL in the same script.  But you could create an INSERT trigger.  Now, I **hate** triggers, but it's one way of doing it.

Depending on what you are trying to do, you might want to insert the rows into a temp table or table variable first, and deal with the result set that way.  Hopefully, there is a unique column that you can link to.

You could also lock the table, get the max key, insert your rows, and then get your max key again and do a range.

**Trigger:**

```
--Use the Inserted table.  This conaints all of the inserted rows.
SELECT * FROM Inserted
```

**Temp Table:**

```
insert field1, unique_col into #temp from tbl_abc

insert into tbl_xyz (field1, unique_col) select field1, unique_col from tbl_abc

--This could be an update, or a cursor, or whatever you want to do
SELECT * FROM tbl_xyz WHERE EXISTS (SELECT top 1 unique_col FROM #temp WHERE unique_col = tbl_xyz.unique_col)
```

**Key Range:**

```
Declare @minkey as int, @maxkey as int

BEGIN TRANS --You have to lock the table for this to work

  --key is the name of your identity column
  SELECT @minkey = MAX(key) FROM tbl_xyz
  insert into tbl_xyz select field1 from tbl_abc
  SELECT @maxkey = MAX(key) FROM tbl_xyz

COMMIT Trans

SELECT * FROM tbl_xyz WHERE key BETWEEN @minkey and @maxkey
```