# Procedure returning a list of identity

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I retrieve the identities of rows that were inserted through insert…select?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/575273/how-can-i-retrieve-the-identities-of-rows-that-were-inserted-through-insert-se)

I need that a procedure that could return a list of Primary Key( auto generated) after of an insert

```
PROCEDURE [dbo].[Person_InsertCloud]
@TablePerson Catalog.Type_Person READONLY
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON
    INSERT INTO dbo.PersonaTestCLOUD
    (IdPerson, IdDocument,NroDocument,Name,LastName, SecondLastName,BrandName, 
     Birthdate, IdSex, IdState, IdTypePerson, IdUbicationGeographic, NumberPhoneDefault,
     IdDirectory,IdPhoto)
    SELECT t.Id,t.IdDocument,t.NroDocument,t.Name,t.LastName,t.SecondLastName,t.BrandName,
        t.BirthDate,t.IdSex,t.IdState, t.IdTypePerson,t.IdUbicationGeographic,t.NumberPhoneDefault,
        t.IdDirectory, t.IdPhoto
    FROM @TablePerson t
    WHERE t.IdServer = -1;
```

Is that possible? I used before a procedure that returns just one id.

Thanks