# Table Value Parameter from c#

Tags: sql-server, ado.net, table-valued-parameters

I have read a number of articles and they all look like the following. When I execute from SSMS everything is fine. When I execute from c#, I get no exceptions. When I check the table, the c# did not insert.

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.Rates
    (Id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY, 
    LocationName NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
    CostRate INT NOT NULL);
GO

/* Create a table type. */
CREATE TYPE dbo.RatesType AS TABLE 
    ( LocationName NVARCHAR(50)
    , CostRate INT );
GO

/* Create a procedure to receive data for the table-valued parameter. */
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.usp_InsertLocationRates
    @TVP RatesType READONLY
    AS 
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    INSERT INTO Rates
            (LocationName
            , CostRate)
        SELECT LocationName, CostRate
        FROM  @TVP;
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.Rates
        (LocationName
        , CostRate)
VALUES ( N'Costa Rica', 38)

DECLARE @T as dbo.RatesType
INSERT INTO @T(LocationName, CostRate)
VALUES('Equador', 24)
EXEC usp_InsertLocationRates @T;

SELECT * FROM DBO.Rates
```

Here is the c# that produces no error and no results.

```cs
try
{
    DataTable table = new DataTable("Items");
    table.Columns.Add("LocationName", typeof(string));
    table.Columns.Add("CostRate", typeof(int));    
    table.Rows.Add("Bali, Indonesia", 43);        

    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SampleDB"].ConnectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();

        var insertCommand = new SqlCommand("usp_InsertLocationRates", connection);
        var tableValueParameter = insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TVP", table);
        tableValueParameter.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
        tableValueParameter.TypeName = "RatesType";

        insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        connection.Close();
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    // No error exists!
}
```

The results after running the SQL and then the c#:

```
Id  | LocationName  | CostRate
1   | Costa Rica    | 38
2   | Equador       | 24
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default `CommandType` is `Text`; you need to specify that the command is for a stored procedure:

```
insertCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

After adding this your code works for me.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using AddWithValue.

Try this instead.

```
insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@TVP", SqlDbType.Udt).Value = table;
```

You might also want to take a peek at this article. http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Comment: Thank you for answering, but there are a few problems with your answer. The first is that the link that you provided is not relevant to this example because I am not inferring the type, I have set it to "Structured". The second problem is that even if we do specify the type as prescribed, we still need to specify the "TypeName". The third problem with your answer is that you are using "Udt" when we need to be using "Structured".