# How do I specify to use server defined values in a Table Valued Parameter when my source is a DataReader?

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-core, sqldatareader, table-valued-parameters

My TVP looks like this::

```sql
create type p_tvp as table
(
   id int identity not null,
   value float not null
)
```

I have some datareader that yields a list of double (not actual SQL executed):

```cs
 using (var conn = new SqlConnection(_srcString)
 using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from (values(1e),(2e),(3e))f(v)", conn))
 {
       await conn.OpenAsync();

       using(var rdr = await _cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync())
       using(var tCon = new SqlConnection(_targetString))
       using(var tcmd = new SqlCommand("MyStoredProcedure",tCon))
       {
         await tCon.OpenAsync();
         tcmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoreProcedure;
         var param = tcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@tvp, rdr);
         param.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
         param.TypeName = "dbo.p_tpv";
         await tcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
       }
 }
```

The error I get is that I don't have enough parameters. As the TVP I'm targeting has 2 columns. If I add a dummy column, the error I get is that I can't identity insert into table valued parameters.

I cannot redefine the TVP.

The other question specifies a `DataTable` as the source, the answer uses a `IEnumerable<SqlDataRecord>`. Unfortunately, neither solves my case of having a `DbDataReader`. I can convert to `SqlDataRecord` if necessary, but I'd like to avoid the extra steps as I cannot easily control the `DbDataReader` source.

Comment: You can use a reader though as well to enable streaming. If you use a datatable you have to materialize the dataset. My actual source database isn't Sql Server.

Comment: Yeah I do that. This again isn't my actual code, but I'll update my example.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Identity column in a table-valued parameter in procedure, how to define DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3210945/identity-column-in-a-table-valued-parameter-in-procedure-how-to-define-datatabl)

Comment: Again, that's for a datatable (the actual answer implements via an `IEnumerable<SqlDataRecord>`. I have a `DbDataReader`.

Comment: You cannot do this with DbDataReader, instead you can "stream" DbDataReader into `IEnumerable<SqlDataRecord>`. With `IEnumerable` you will enumerate rows one at the time, without materialising whole data.

Answer (score 0):

As Fabio noted in a comment on the question, you can use `IEnumerable<SqlDataRecord>` to set up a custom data structure via `SqlDataRecord` and then stream the results from the `SqlDataReader` into the TVP.

In the following example, the "id" column of the TVP uses the `SqlMetaData` constructor that allows for setting `useServerDefault` to `true`. The `yield break` should safely exit if no rows were returned from the original query.

```csharp
private IEnumerable<SqlDataRecord> SendRowsToProc(SqlDataReader reader)
{
  if (!reader.HasRows)
  {
    yield break;
  }

  SqlDataRecord resultRow = new SqlDataRecord(new SqlMetaData[] {
             new SqlMetaData("id", SqlDbType.Int, true, true, SortOrder.Unspecified, 0),
             new SqlMetaData("value", SqlDbType.Float)
                                                    });

  while (reader.Read())
  {
    resultRow.SetDouble(1, reader.GetDouble(0));

    yield return resultRow;
  }
}
```

And so, rather than passing in `rdr` as the "value" of the TVP `SqlParameter`, you pass in: `SendRowsToProc(rdr)`.

---

Another option to consider, if you *really* want to pass `rdr` in as the TVP value:

1. Use a different UDTT, one that has the same `ID INT NOT NULL` column, but that is *not* marked as being an `IDENTITY`
2. In your `SELECT` statement (at the source), start the column list with:

   ```
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY @@MICROSOFTVERSION) AS [ID]
   ```

That should provide the same functionality that the `IDENTITY` column is currently providing. Of course, it won't work if you are executing a stored procedure, but for the case given in the question, it should be fine.

Comment: Yeah, I went down this road. Unfortunately, this felt like a kind of ugly hack that I had to do.
Also as an aside, for stylistic purposes, locals and parameters are specified in camelCase. PascalCase is reserved for classes and public members and the `_` usually specifies a private member.

Comment: @MichaelB Not sure that I agree with it being _that_ hacky. Maybe slightly, but not that bad. Maybe there is a way, using Reflection, to modify the internal `SqlDataRecord` / `DbDataRecord` being used by the `SqlDataReader`, so that it's definition has `useServerDefault` set to `true` :-). Either way, I added a long-shot second option to my answer. Just something to consider :-).