# transaction concept in sql server using stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to insert one data into another table..after this step I need to fetch that inserted data only from that table...this whole I have to do using single stored procedure..using the concept of transactions in sql.

like I have one table `abc` that having content

```
id name
1  ashu
```

now I have inserted new data in it

```
id name
2  ashish
```

I don't know the data which I have inserted...I'm doing this by stored procedure...now I need those data which are inserted by this.

Comment: The question title says sql server but you tagged this with plsql, what database are you using?

Comment: Can you show the stored procedure you have written?

Comment: my stored procedure is inserting more than one record at a time..and i want all those records only from that table...for that what i have to do....for single record fetching i can use @@identity property...but for multiple records what to do...help me out guys...please

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to insert multiple records and get the identity value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/95988/how-to-insert-multiple-records-and-get-the-identity-value) Please make sure you look at the answer with the most votes in that question, not the accepted answer. You can use the [`OUTPUT` clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@@IDENTITY` or `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` in `SQL SERVER` to return the last inserted identity, so at the end of your Stored Procedure do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM YOUR_TABLE WHERE ID = @@IDENTITY
```

This will return the last row that was inserted.

See [MSDN for information on @@IDENTITY AND SCOPE_IDENTITY()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms190315.aspx)

Comment: @tanner.....your answer is correct in the case when i am inserting only one row..that will be fetched by @@identity property...if my stored procedure is inserting more than one record at a time..and i want all those records only from that table...for that what i have to do....

Comment: For multiple inserts, you could create a comma separated string to concatenate all of the identities as they are inserted "1,2,3,4" then use an `IN` clause on the `WHERE` clause so it would be WHERE ID IN(1,2,3,4).

Comment: @tannan....but where i am inserting there i am already having uniqueids..so i can not hardcode...i do't know which id will generate for inserted records..without knowing id i want those 50 or 100 rows..

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution for this. I am using:

```
Output inserted.SNO into @temp
```

From this command all the inserted rows will come in this temp table. So I am able to proceed to next steps.