# Multiple Output Into in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have four tables: A,B,C,D. A has PK of B, B has PK of C and C has PK of D.
I want to insert data to all of them. I have tried using Output Into by using 
two tables

```
declare @a table(
no int identity(1,2),
nama varchar(30)
)

declare @b table(
no int identity(1,1),
nama varchar(40)
)
insert into @b (name) values('test')
merge @a 
using @b 
on 0=1
when not matched
then insert (nama)
Values ('test2')
output inserted.no, inserted.nama into @b;

select * from  @b
```

How can I add more Output Into so I can insert PK of @b to another table?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to insert multiple records and get the identity value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/95988/how-to-insert-multiple-records-and-get-the-identity-value)

Comment: its not duplicate

Comment: It might help others if you state why it isn't a duplicate.